# Algorithm for finding path combinations?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, linear-algebra

Imagine you have a dancing robot in `n`-dimensional euclidean space starting at origin `P_0` = `(0,0,...,0)`.

The robot can make `m` types of dance moves `D_1, D_2, ..., D_m`

`D_i` is an `n`-vector of integers `(D_i_1, D_i_2, ..., D_i_n)`

If the robot makes dance move `i` than its position changes by `D_i`:

`P_{t+1} = P_t + D_i`

The robot can make any of the dance moves as many times as he wants and in any order.

Let a *k-dance* be defined as a sequence of k dance moves.

Clearly there are `m^k` possible k-dances.

*We are interested to know the set of possible end positions of a k-dance, and for each end position, how many k-dances end at that location.*

One way to do this is as follows:

```
P0 = (0, 0, ..., 0);

S[0][P0] = 1

for I in 1 to k
    for J in 1 to m
        for P in S[I-1]
            S[I][P + D_J] += S[I][P]
```

Now `S[k][Q]` will tell you how many k-dances end at position Q

Assume that `n`, `m`, `|D_i|` are small (less than 5) and `k` is less than 40.

Is there a faster way?  Can we calculate `S[k][Q]` "directly" somehow with some sort of linear algebra related trick? or some other approach?

Comment: +1 for dancing robot in n-dimensional Euclidean space

Comment: have you tried using rules and let HMM handle it for you?? do you think it's applicable in your case??

Answer (score 1):

You could create an adjacency matrix that would contain dance-move transitions in your space (the part of it that's reachable in k moves, otherwise it would be infinite). Then, the P_0 row of n-th power of this matrix contains the S[k] values.

The matrix in question quickly gets enormous, something like `(k*(max(D_i_j)-min(D_i_j)))^n` (every dimension can be halved if Q is close to origin), but that's true for your `S` matrix as well

Answer (score 1):

Since the 1-dimensional problem is closely related to the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), you could probably take a similar approach - find all of the combinations of dance vectors that add together to have the correct first coordinate with exactly k moves; then take that subset of combinations and check to see which of those have the right sum for the second, and take the subset which matches both and check it for the third, and so on.

In this way, you get to at least only have to perform a very simple addition for the extremely painful O(n^k) step.  It will indeed find all of the vectors which will hit a given value.

Comment: When you say add together to have the correct first value `P_0_0`, what is `P_0_0`?  I have defined `P_0` as the zero vector and origin.  Did you mean `P_0`?

Comment: Assuming you mean `P_0`, how do I find all of the combinations of dance vectors that add together to `P_0`?

Comment: The pseudo polynomial time algorithm described on that page is closely analogous;  the advantage you have is that the number of elements which can be used to hit the sum is bounded to exactly k.

Comment: Also, sorry, what I meant was the first coordinate of a given end position.

Answer (score 1):

Since dance moves are interchangable you can assume that for a `i < j` the robot first makes all the `D_i` moves before the `D_j` moves, thus reducing the number of combinations to actually calculate.

If you keep track of the number of times each dance move was made calculating the total number of combinations should be easy.

Comment: In my example algorithm `S[i]` is calculated based on `S[i-1]`.  Each `S[i]` is a histogram of position vectors (at time i).  Using your method for one entry in this histogram I would only have the count of nondecreasing sequences (not any sequence).  In the end how do I convert these counts of nondecreasing sequences to counts of any sequences as required, given each entry is a mixture of many different nondecreasing sequences?

Comment: Instead of just the end position and number of paths, you'd keep track of end position plus number of uses for each dance step (N_i). The total number of combinations reaching that postion is then k!/Sum(N_i!)

Comment: At each element of `S[t][p]`, there are `(t+m+1 choose m)` possible combinations.  Therefore this would increase the required storage and performance by a factor of this amount?  Therefore isn't this much worse than my original suggested algorithm?

Comment: I don't follow that argument. The storage would only increase significantly I think if the number of P_x it large that can be reached by different distinct combinations of D_y. Because those have to maintained as different histograms, while in your algorithm they are stored in one node. On the other side you have less combinations to calculate, which should make the most significant effect when the k >> m. So I'd expect for k >> m my algorithm to be more efficient while for k << m yours to be more efficient ??